# I don't have permission to save the theme options I created myself?

Tags: admin, theme-options, options, capabilities

I created an option panel following a tutorial.

But each time I try to save the settings I get the following:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Any suggestions to fix this?

*(Not sure if this helps but I'm using Wordpress 3.1.2)*

**EDIT:**

I don't have the permission issue if I place the code directly in the `functions.php` file in my theme folder.

I have the file in `functions/custom-functions.php`. I have to change the 'header Location,' not sure how:

```
function mytheme_add_admin() {
    global $themename, $shortname, $options;

    if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {
        if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            foreach ($options as $value)
                update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] );

            foreach ($options as $value) {
                if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) )
                    update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  );
                else
                    delete_option( $value['id'] );
            }
            header("Location: admin.php?page=functions.php&saved=true");
            die;
        }
        else if ( 'reset' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
            foreach ($options as $value)
                delete_option( $value['id'] );

            header("Location: admin.php?page=functions.php&reset=true");
            die;
        }
    }
    add_menu_page($themename, $themename, 'administrator', basename(__FILE__), 'mytheme_admin');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the menu page using the "administrator" role. Is the account you're using an administrator?

Note:

1) You should be using an appropriate *capability*, rather than a *user role*. Generally, the appropriate capability for editing Theme options is `edit_theme_options`.

2) There is a known bug with WordPress, in that currently, `manage_options` is required for the form submit on `options.php`, which is used by Theme settings pages. This is only an issue for user roles below editor, and will hopefully be fixed in 3.2 or 3.3.

3) If this is a public Theme, you should be using `add_theme_page()` (which adds a submenu to the "Appearance" menu), rather than `add_menu_page()` (which adds a top-level menu page).

4) That tutorial is considerably out of date.

Comment: Thanks for helping again. Can you give me an example for 1)? How would that code look like (Which lines I have to replace)?

Comment: @janoChen: the third argument in `add_menupage()` currently is `'administrator'`; change it to `'edit_theme_options'`.

Comment: 2) <- this helped me a lot to fix a different problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two changes in your code...

1. Change the third argument of `add_menu_page` from `"administrator"` to `"edit_theme_options"`.
2. Chage `header("Location:")` code line to...

`header("Location: admin.php?page=" . basename(__FILE__) . "&saved=true");`

Please make similar change for Reset.